# SQL SERVER Counting values for an ID

Tags: count, distinct, grouping

I'm trying to get a count of B.ID's for each C.ID.

So far I'm getting the following:

[image]

```
Select
C.ID,
COUNT(Distinct B.ID)AS 'Total bookings'

FROM Client C

inner join Booking B on B.ClientID=C.ID

Where ClientID = '594861'

Group by C.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with my Group by!

```
Select
C.ID,
COUNT(Distinct B.ID)AS 'Total bookings'

FROM Client C

inner join Booking B on B.ClientID=C.ID

Where ClientID = '594861'

Group by C.ID
```